# Schengen visa validity

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I have a schengen visa validity from 13\6\2018 until 27\6\2018 and the duration of stay is 15 days , if i enter to schengen area at 20\6\2018 can i stay 15 days count start from enter means leaving on 10\7\2018 ?

Comment: The fifteenth day for someone arriving on June 20th is July 4th.  How  did you come up with July 10th?

Comment: You've put the UK tag on this question. Note that the UK is not part of Schengen.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You must comply with *both* the period of validity and the duration of stay.  You may not stay beyond 27 June with that visa.

Comment: how can i extend days on visa ?

Comment: @user78052: You can't (except in very specific circumstances). If you want to travel in a way not allowed by your current visa you'll need to apply for a new one.